# CSS3 and pixel unit

Tags: css, pixel

In the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths) pixel unit are defined as an absolute length while
in many CSS books as relative. What's the true?

Comment: Always trust the spec. Also ask yourself "How can a pixel _be_ a relative unit?" Pixels don't grow or shrink, they are a specific size.

Comment: yes its true pixel is always absolute, it has a fixed size...

Answer (score 1):

To quote the second paragraph from [5.2 of your link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths), emphasis mine:

> For a CSS device, these dimensions are either anchored (i) by relating
>   the physical units to their physical measurements, or **(ii) by relating
>   the pixel unit to the reference pixel.**

That means that based on certain conditions, 1 pixel is equal to 1/96 inch. This however is almost never the case due to widely varying pixel densities and screen dimensions nowadays.

Comment: i wouldn't say contradictory, i'd just say the specs make a wrong assumption about all screens being 96 ppi.

Answer (score 0):

Pixels are absolute length always. They are the [smallest screen element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel) you can control so it has a fixed size (different between different screens, but a fixed size for one screen) so it's not fluid or relative at all.

Anyway, what the specification says is always true. If they make a mistake, then it becomes true for what they are specificating :)